# can not get array value of a simple array in php

Tags: php

`$color_hash` is an stdObject

```
stdClass Object
(
    [07] => GRAY
    [67] => BLUE
)
```

`print_r($color_hash);` 
return

```
stdClass Object ( [07] => GRAY [67] => BLUE )
```

I convert `$color_hash` to an array

```
$colour_hash_array = (array)$colour_hash;
```

return

```
Array
(
    [07] => GRAY
    [67] => BLUE
)
```

Tried

```
var_dump($colour_hash_array);
```

return

```
array(2) { ["07"]=> string(4) "GRAY" ["67"]=> string(4) "BLUE" }
```

I try

```
log_me($colour_hash_array['07']);//Return GRAY

log_me($colour_hash_array['67']);//Return empty. HERE IS THE PROBLEM


function log_me($message) {
    if (WP_DEBUG === true) {
        if (is_array($message) || is_object($message)) {
            error_log(print_r($message, true));
        } else {
            error_log($message);
        }
    }
}
```

That is so strange.
Where i am wrong?

using

```
 foreach($colour_hash_array as $color)
    {
        log_me($color);

    }
```

print

[26-Mar-2016 07:04:11 Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh] GRAY

[26-Mar-2016 07:04:11 Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh] BLUE

UPDATE:

I tried to create an array

```
$colour_hash_array = array("07" => "GRAY","67"=>"BLUE");

log_me($colour_hash_array['07']);//Return GRAY
log_me($colour_hash_array['67']);//Return BLUE
```

This works. I can not understand any more :(

Comment: and what does the log_me do exactly?

Comment: even though I try $c = $colour_hash_array['67']; echo $c; it return empty

Comment: That's odd! And how is $colour_hash_array defined in the code?

Comment: I updated my question, how is $colour_hash_array  defined

Comment: how you use php version? Your code work is fine for me in php 5.6

Comment: I'm guessing there's something off with your key-values, so you can do `print_r(var_dump(array_keys($arr)));` to print all your keys. Or you can do it in a loop, like `foreach($colour_hash_array as $key=>$color) { var_dump($key); }`

Comment: my php version  is  5.6.15

Comment: @Qirel it returns string(2) "07" string(2) "67"

Comment: have you enable php errors? some php notice can be relevant to find out the problem.

Comment: yes, but it dont receive any php notice.

Comment: there's more relevant code that you don't show us?

Comment: no, it is all the code. Btw, i try to create $colour_hash_array = array("07" => "GRAY","67"=>"BLUE"); and then print log_me($colour_hash_array['67']); This work. So I dont understand where is the problem.

Comment: how did you create the stdClass object that then you cast in an array?

Comment: stdClass object is retrieved from $json = json_decode( $matches[1] ); I have teamview, anybody want to try?

Comment: I'm honestly quite puzzled by this, as you said the key is a string with value 67, and then doing `$colour_hash_array['67']` isn't working for you (which uses the string 67 as a key for that value). Because that *really should* work..

Comment: trust me. you can log in to my computer with teamview

Comment: I gave up. I will just use forearch to read elements and save to an array. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You want to return an associative array, which you're trying to do by casting the decoded json (which is an object) into an array. But that doesn't work properly, as you might've seen already. However, the second parameter in the `json_decode` function is to set the decoder to return an associative array instead of an object - which is exactly what you're looking for. An example of it here:

```
$encoded = json_encode(array("07" => "GRAY","67"=>"BLUE"));

$decoded = json_decode($encoded);             // Returns stdClass-object
$decoded_array = json_decode($encoded, true); // Return an associative array, 
                                              // which is what you're looking for
```

You can see the `var_dumps()` of `$decoded` and `$decoded_array` to be respectively

```
// var_dump($decoded);
object(stdClass)#7 (2) { 
    ["07"]=> string(4) "GRAY" 
    ["67"]=> string(4) "BLUE" 
} 

// var_dump($decoded_array);
array(2) { 
    ["07"]=> string(4) "GRAY" 
    [67]=> string(4) "BLUE" 
}
```

**The solution**

So where you define `$colour_hash`, you simply need to add a second parameter `true` to the `json_decode` function, making it like this

```
$colour_hash_array = json_decode($matches[1], true);
```

---

The result of your output should be

```
log_me($colour_hash_array['07']); //Returns GRAY
log_me($colour_hash_array['67']); //Returns BLUE
```

**References**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

When you define your array, you're using integers for your keys (I should say I am assuming this, but it's what seems most likely to me).

So this:

```
$arr = [
    07 => 'GRAY',
    67 => 'BLUE'
];
```

Results in this:

```
Array(
    7 => 'GRAY',
    67 => 'BLUE
)
```

See how the 0 was dropped from the front of the key? An integer doesn't store that zero.

To reference that key, you can use `$arr[7]` or `$arr['7']`.

---

If it is important for you to keep that zero, then use a string to define your key, instead of an integer, and the zero should remain:

So this:

```
$arr = [
    '07' => 'GRAY',
    '67' => 'BLUE'
];
```

Results in this:

```
Array(
    '07' => 'GRAY',
    '67' => 'BLUE
)
```

Now that the key is a string, you **have** to reference it is as the exact string, so only `$arr['07']` will work now.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That `0` is just the octal notation. 07 (base 8) == 7 (base 10). In this case `$arr[07], $arr[7], $arr['7']` give the same result.

Comment: Agreed, if the key is defined as an integer, in base 10 or 8, `$arr[07]`, `$arr[7]`, and `$arr['7']` should work just fine, though `$arr['07']` will not. However, if the key is defined as a string, then `$arr['07']` will work and `$arr[07]`, `$arr[7]`, and `$arr['7']` will throw an `Undefined offset` error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my previus stupid answer, I reproduce this behavior, please see code:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

function log_me($message) {
    if (WP_DEBUG === true) {
        if (is_array($message) || is_object($message)) {
            error_log(print_r($message, true));
        } else {
            error_log($message);
        }
    }
}
//decode json and convert to array
$colour_hash_array = (array)json_decode('{"07":"GREY", "67":"BLUE", "09":"BLACK"}');

print_r($colour_hash_array);   

foreach($colour_hash_array as $key => $color) {
   print 'type:' . gettype($key) . ':' . $key . "\n";
}

log_me($colour_hash_array['07']);//Return GRAY

log_me($colour_hash_array['67']);//undefine offset

log_me($colour_hash_array['09']);//Return BLACK
```

But if we use get_object_vars for convert object to array, this code work is fine:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

function log_me($message) {
    if (WP_DEBUG === true) {
        if (is_array($message) || is_object($message)) {
            error_log(print_r($message, true));
        } else {
            error_log($message);
        }
    }
}

//decode json and convert to array
$colour_hash_array = get_object_vars(json_decode('{"07":"GREY", "67":"BLUE", "09":"BLACK"}'));

print_r($colour_hash_array);


foreach($colour_hash_array as $key => $color) {
   print 'type:' . gettype($key) . ':' . $key . "\n";
}

log_me($colour_hash_array['07']);//Return GRAY

log_me($colour_hash_array['67']);//Return BLUE

log_me($colour_hash_array['09']);//Return BLACK
```